# Can I reuse a where clause with many conditions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am migrating many MySQL queries from being hard-coded in a Node.js app to stored procedures (for use in a Java app). In the original Node app there is one SQL condition saved as a constant string that is substituted into many different SQL functions as part of the where clause and I cannot figure out how to accomplish the same thing using MySQL stored functions.

The constant is a SQL string that checks whether a variety of properties are null on a user object:

```js
const USER_INFO_NOT_NULL = `u.id IS NOT NULL \
  AND u.email IS NOT NULL \
  AND u.gender IS NOT NULL \
  AND u.date_of_birth IS NOT NULL \
  AND u.first_name IS NOT NULL \
  AND u.last_name IS NOT NULL`
```

This SQL statement is substituted into many different queries as one of the conditions in their `WHERE` statement.

For example:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) count
    FROM User u
    WHERE ${USER_INFO_NOT_NULL} 
        AND some_other_condition
        AND another_condition
...
```

Unfortunately, not all of the queries are as simple as the one above and it would be a lot of work to rewrite each one.

I've tried using a stored function, however, stored functions can only take scalar values as parameters so I cannot pass along a user row.

I've also tried having the function take the user id (not ideal as the queries have already queried the user), query for that user and return a boolean based on the above condition. However, I'm not sure how to combine a `SELECT` with a `RETURN` in a stored function (can you do this?).

I've looked into prepared statements, however, they don't seem to work in this way as they only support a limited number of SQL commands.

So, is there a way to do something similar to what already exists in the Node.js app using only MySQL features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a view.

```
CREATE VIEW user_info_not_null 
SELECT *
FROM User u
WHERE u.id IS NOT NULL 
  AND u.email IS NOT NULL 
  AND u.gender IS NOT NULL 
  AND u.date_of_birth IS NOT NULL 
  AND u.first_name IS NOT NULL 
  AND u.last_name IS NOT NULL;
```

Then you can use the view like a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count
FROM user_info_not_null
WHERE some_other_condition
AND another_condition
```

In a stored procedure you should be able to do this with a prepared statement.

```
SET user_info_not_null = 'u.id IS NOT NULL 
  AND u.email IS NOT NULL 
  AND u.gender IS NOT NULL 
  AND u.date_of_birth IS NOT NULL 
  AND u.first_name IS NOT NULL 
  AND u.last_name IS NOT NULL';
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) count
    FROM User u
    WHERE ', user_info_not_null, '
        AND some_other_condition
        AND another_condition');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You can also substitute the `WHERE` clause into templates:

```
set template_sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) count
    FROM User u
    WHERE ${user_info_not_null}
        AND some_other_condition
        AND another_condition';
set @sql = REPLACE(template_sql, '${user_info_not_null}', user_info_not_null);
```

Comment: This works but would require a significant rewrite of each query to use a view. For example, one particularly long query has three instances of that single `WHERE` clause with multiple nested `SELECT` statements. Again, I'd like to avoid rewriting a bunch of queries...optimization isn't within the scope of this task.

Comment: you talked about using stored functions, wouldn't that be just as much rewriting?

Comment: No, I'm simply copy/pasting the existing hardcoded SQL queries into a template I have for creating stored procedures. The problem is that some of the queries use JS string-substitution to construct a complex where clause with multiple conditions. I'd like to be able to reuse that where clause condition if possible so I don't have to copy/paste the string into each query myself, which would make it a nightmare to change.

Comment: Both of those approaches seem like they could work. Would it be possible to set `user_info_not_null` to a user-defined variable so I can access it from multiple queries? Also, would using either of these approaches with a prepared procedure cause issues?

Comment: BTW, you should probably put parentheses around the common where clause, to avoid issues if it's mixed with `OR` conditions.